# SharePoint 2007 Variation Sporadic Notification

Tags: notifications, sharepoint-2007

We've created a SharePoint 2007 website that uses variations for our different locales.  When someone makes a change to a page on the source variation and publishes it.  It is supposed to send out a notification to the owner of the variation site.

Currently, we are receiving sporadic notifications.  Sometimes our authors will receive an email or not and sometimes they will receive a notification but for the wrong variation.

My question is:

What is the field that SharePoint uses in order to determine whom to send out the email notification to?

Page Author (Contact)?
Site owner?
Site Author?

And does this need to be set on each page/site or just at the variation root?

Answer (score 1):

There are few things to remember in this case.

1. If you are creating a new page, then the email will go to the contact person of welcome page of that site.
2. If you are modifying a page, then the email will go to the contact person of that page.

Example: if you create a new page in site xyz and the welcome page on the variation site is `default.aspx`, then you have to set the contact person for this page; and email will be received by this user when a new page is created.

If you modifying a page called `ourcompany.aspx`, then in the variation site, check who is the contact person for `ourcompany.aspx`; this user will get email when this page will be modified.